# Access Denied error in WSO2 remote instance connection on G-Reg registry (4.1)

Tags: esb, wso2

I created an ESB service and tried to load remote instance from G-Reg registry. My ESB and G-Reg use same MySQL DB, JVM, OS.

And then two error log messages have been printed in my console: 
(1)ERROR - RegistryAdminServiceClient Error occurred while checking registry mode
(2)org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Please login first.

What does "Please login first" & "checking registry mode" mean? Where should I login? What is registry mode?

Answer (score 1):

This exception normally occurs when you are logged out from server backend. Checking Registry mode means it tries to check if the Registry is read only or not.